# Why does Apollo cache (?) writeQuery() re render a query component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm working on a React project using Apollo Client and there is a `cache.writeQuery()` call being made that is causing a re render of a related query component.

See code for details:

> cache.writeQuery():

```
cache.writeQuery( {
    query : serverQueries.searchMessages,
    variables : {
        labelId : labelId,
        searchTerms : searchTermsString ? searchTermsString : null,
        )
    },

    data : { Messages : updatedData }
} );
```

> Related query component that is re rendering:

```
<SearchMessagesQuery
            query={serverQueries.searchMessages}
            variables={{
                labelId: searchMailLabelId,
                searchTerms: searchTerms.asJSON,
            }}>
```

I do not want this query component to re render and from what I've read it seems as though `cache.writeData()` allows that behaviour. However, `cache.writeData()` apparently does not allow the `variable` key which I would need to update unique/individual `searchMessages`. How can I use `cache.writeData()` in order to execute the same query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cache.writeData()` usage for updating single item (by type) is described [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state#local-resolvers)

But ... I'm affraid it will force rerender query component, too. This behaviour is from `<Query/>` component internals - creating an observable/subscription:

> Apollo Client creates an observable for our query. Our component subscribes to the result of the query via the Apollo Client cache.

**SUGGESTION**:
You can use *old* `graphql()` HOC to avoid rerendering with `cache.writeQuery()`. I personally prefer HOCs using more flexible/powerfull [recompose pattern](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/recompose) (f.e. for composing multiple queries, mutations, local state, redux `connect()` ).